# Magento 2: Programmatically Updating Inventory

Tags: magento2, inventory, magento-2.0, programmatically

In the following code, I am able to store all the information with the exclusion of the stock data.  Has something changed in Magento 2?

```
public function __construct(
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, CollectionFactory $product,
    Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function update(\XXXXXX\XXXXXX\Api\Data\InventoryCollectionInterface $data) {
    foreach ($data['list'] as $d) {
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($d['entity_id']);
        $product->setStatus(($d['quantity'] > 0 ? 1 : 0));
        $product->setUpc($d['upc']);
        $product->setStockData(array(
            'qty' => $d['quantity'],
            'is_in_stock' => ($d['quantity'] > 0 ? 1 : 0)
        ));

        $this->productRepository->save($product);
    }

    return "Done";
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5771

Answer (score 40):

This works for me:

```
$item = ['qty' => 11]; // For example
$product->setStockData(['qty' => $item['qty'], 'is_in_stock' => $item['qty'] > 0]);
$product->save();
```

**Edit**:

This is no longer the correct way to handle this, because `$product->save()` is deprecated since Magento 2.1. The correct way to do this is by using the `StockRegistryInterface`:

```
/**
 * @var StockRegistryInterface
 */
protected $stockRegistry;

/**
 * Inventory constructor.
 * @param StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
 */
public function __construct(
    StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
)
{
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    parent::__construct();
}
```

With the above code, you can use the following:

```
$sku = 'ABC123';
$qty = 10;
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
```

Use **Managers** as much as possible. Keep your modules decoupled from each other.

It's The Magento Way™

Comment: setStockData is what is required. There is no need to call ->setQuantityAndStockStatuses, though it seems to do no harm.

Comment: It works great for one product. However, when you reading a CSV file with 5k SKUs the performance is pretty bad. Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: Really appreciate the Updated Method! Magento is getting better for all of us because of community members like you doing posts like this! Way to go

Comment: can you help me on this question? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270215/update-product-stock-quantity-programmatically-via-csv-loading-but-not-saving

Comment: Can you help me for this question ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279823/magento-2-product-quantity-update-programatically-if-product-status-is-disable/279853#279853

Comment: And what to do with new product? Did `getStockItemBySku($sku);` returns something?

Comment: And now this is also a deprecated way. Man, I don't know if I feel like the platform is always moving forward or if it just don't gets enough planning

Answer (score 22):

If you are using the @giel-berkers solution, you may need to set isInStock also, because it will not be automatically sets.
So, the following code was useful for me:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
)
{
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function yourMethod() {
    $sku = 'ABC123';
    $qty = 10;
    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty); // this line
    $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
}
```

Comment: how can i use this answer to update the qty store wise in magento 2?

Comment: @Mujahidh you can try to pass scopeId as a second parameter to the `getStockItemBySku()` method

Comment: thanks, qty is updating but not store wise, for both store updating the same qty.

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with this same issue. While debugging I found that the product data has a quantity_and_stock_status array, so I tried setting it with:

```
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $quantity, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
```

and it started working for me. I still am setting the $product->setStockData too if you edit a product and inspect element on the fields you'll see it has both, one is on the general tab, the other on the advanced inventory fields. I have not fully investigated why there are 2 of them.

Comment: sort and simple , very good solution !!! works for me +1

Comment: Preferred solution, as this works and takes way less editing than the others +1

Comment: When product is Disable then quantity not update; else in enable status working properly. Can you help me for it. My site is in 2.1.9

Answer (score 8):

One thing the other answers missed is that if you `setQty($qty)`, it will apply the exact value you provide. But if a sale was made for that product a moment before your save, the original qty could have changed. So what you really want to do is tell Magento the *difference* you want to apply to the qty.

Fortunately, Magento 2 provides a nice mechanism for this. Take a look at `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item`:

```
protected function _prepareDataForTable(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object, $table)
{
    $data = parent::_prepareDataForTable($object, $table);
    $ifNullSql = $this->getConnection()->getIfNullSql('qty');
    if (!$object->isObjectNew() && $object->getQtyCorrection()) {
        if ($object->getQty() === null) {
            $data['qty'] = null;
        } elseif ($object->getQtyCorrection() < 0) {
            $data['qty'] = new \Zend_Db_Expr($ifNullSql . '-' . abs($object->getQtyCorrection()));
        } else {
            $data['qty'] = new \Zend_Db_Expr($ifNullSql . '+' . $object->getQtyCorrection());
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Here we see that if you set the `qty_correction` value, it will apply the difference incrementally instead of applying an exact amount.

So my suggestion for a safer qty save is this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
 */
protected $stockRegistry;

public function __construct(StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry)
{
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}

/**
* Set the quantity in stock for a product
*
*/
public function applyNewQty($sku, $newQty)
{
    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
    $origQty = $stockItem->getQty();
    $difference = $newQty - $origQty;
    $stockItem->setQtyCorrection($difference);
    $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);

    // note that at this point, $stockItem->getQty() is incorrect, so you'll need to reload if you need that value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$stockRegistry = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

$stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty);
$stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento2 also come up with Multi stock feature so to update on particular stock source you can follow this solution

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272296/how-to-set-qty-to-product-on-msi-magento-2-3
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working fine for me to update product qty,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
) {
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}

public function updateQty(){
    $sku = '24-mb01';
    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku($sku);
    if($productId){
        $product->load($productId);
    }

    $product->setStockData(
        array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
            'manage_stock' => 1,
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 10
        )
    );

    try {
        $product->save(); 
        echo $sku.' updated. '; 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getException();
    }
}
```

Comment: When product status is disable then quantity not update in my case. Can you help me for solve it.

Comment: Calling `save` on an entity (e,g, product) has been deprecated for a while now. Use a repository or resource model instead.

Comment: You can use resource model to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

you can use product repository to update:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface as ProductRepositoryInterface;

$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

$availableQty = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem->setQty($updateQty)->setIsInStock(true);

$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to do this as a mass update for a list of skus and qtys, everyone here has missed on key aspect to setProcessIndexEvents(false);

Code to prevent "The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again" error would be as follows

```
$allrecords = []; // Your array of records that need to be updated

foreach ($allrecords as $record) {

  $sku = $record['sku'];
  $qty = $record['qty'];

    try {
            $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
            $stockItem = false;
        }

   if(!$stockItem) continue;

        /* SET STOCK LEVEL */
   $stockItem->setQty($qty);
   /* PREVENT The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again */
   $stockItem->setProcessIndexEvents(false);  
   $stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty);
   $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
}
```

Doing this prevents the need to turn your indexes to scheduled only and can be left on update on save.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set StoreId to $product before all, and maybe replace:

`$product->setStockData(...)` for `$product->setData('stock_data', '...') // A Paranoid Recommendation`

BTW If you look the Save ActionController at the backend M2 uses a filter for prepare stock_data you could find that filter in:

> Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\StockDataFilter

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that option did not work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, while saving the product in admin, they saved inventory data by using event **catalog_product_save_after** in `Magento_CatalogInventory` module observer

> Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\SaveInventoryDataObserver

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for magento 2.0.9 and following code is working in my case

```
$productStock = $this->_productRepository->getById($item->getMageproductId());
$productStock->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => 12, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
$res = $productStock->save();
```