# Magento 2.3.5: What is the correct technique to update stock?

Tags: product, magento2.3, stock

I have tried to follow the next solution:
[Magento 2: Programmatically Updating Inventory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96519/magento-2-programmatically-updating-inventory)

But in Magento 2.3.5 this solution is deprecated.
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface

Currently what is the solution to update stock?

My code:

```
public function updateProductStockByData(array $data)
{
    $skuArray = $this->getMapWithSkuKey($data);

    try {
        $productIds = $this->getMapWithProductIdKey($skuArray);
        if (count($productIds)) {
            $searchCriteria = $this->getSearchCriteria($productIds);
            $stockItemCollection = $this->stockItemRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
            if ($stockItemCollection->getTotalCount()) {
                /** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item $stockItem */
                foreach ($stockItemCollection->getItems() as $stockItem) {
                    $newQty = $this->dataDictionaryWithProductIdKey[$stockItem->getProductId()]['STOCK'];
                    $stockItem->setQty($newQty);
                    if ($stockItem->getQty() == 0) {
                        $stockItem->setIsInStock(false);
                    }
                    $this->stockItemRepository->save($stockItem);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $this->reportManager->reportNewStockException($exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @chdzma, this was answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325544/proper-way-to-update-stock-in-2-4

Answer (score 1):

Take my answer with a grain of salt. I have a natural tendency to do every CRUD operation using webservices, in the case of Magento, the REST library made available out of the box is awesome. So in order to accomplish the operation you described you can do the following Webservice call:

[image]

I've done this in Postman but if you need any further help using Magento webservices let me know ;)

You can find more info on Magento 2 Webservices here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/